# "yum install package" or "python setup.py install" in CentOS?

Tags: python

I was wondering how the above "yum install package" & "python setup.py install" are used differently in CentOS? I used yum install ... all the time. However, when I try to do python setup.py install, I always get: this setup.py file couldn't be found even though its path shows up under echo $PATH, unless I try to use it in its current directory or use the absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

When you type `python setup.py install`, your shell will check your $PATH for the `python` command, and run that. Then, python will be examining its arguments, which are `setup.py install`. It knows that it can be given the name of a script, so it looks for the file called `setup.py` so it can be run. Python doesn't use your $PATH to find scripts, though, so it should be a real path to a file. If you just give it the name `setup.py` it will only look in your current directory.

The source directory for a python module should not, ideally, be in your $PATH.

`yum install` is a command that will go to a package repository, download all the files needed to install something, and then put them in the right place. `yum` (and equivalents on other distributions, like `apt` for Debian systems) will also fetch and install any other packages you need, including any that aren't python modules.

Python has a package manager, too. You may also find using `pip install modulename` or `pip install --user modulename` (if you don't have administrative rights) easier than downloading and installing the module by hand. You can often get more recent versions of modules this way, as the ones provided by an operating system (through `yum`) tend to be older, more stable versions. Sometimes the module is not available through `yum` at all. `pip` can't install any extra packages that aren't python modules, though.

If you don't have pip already (it comes with Python3, but might need installing separately for Python2, depending on how it was set up), then you can install it by following the instructions here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: The one detail I'd like to see added to this answer is an elaboration of the distinction of your distro's package manager and Python's. Briefly, if you have other RPM (or `.deb` or whatever) packages which depend on a particular distro package, you should probably install that in preference of the `pip` module. (I'm sure this has been answered before many times, though.)

Comment: I think there's arguments both ways. The system package manager is certainly simpler, and the ability to install non-python dependencies makes it attractive for operational reasons. Using pip & virtualenv when distributing software gives you more control over versioning and is more portable. The join between those two routes is to use something like [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/wiki) to make .deb/.rpm from pip modules and your own directory tree.

Comment: I've added more explanation, following your suggestion.